# Annotations to Tile scheme in British National Grid

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, tiles, annotation, tiling-scheme

I am trying to export annotations as a tile in ArcGIS Pro, to be used in conjunction with an OS base map in ArcGIS Online. I need the tile to be exported in British National Grid. Below is the auto suggested scheme but this only goes to a maximum of **level 18**, when I need it to go to **Level 22**.

[image]

I have tried using the ArcGIS online/ Bing Maps/ Google maps option, however the tile created using this option is not in British National Grid and I am unable to change it as there is no option to do so. The resulting tile can not be used with the OS basemap.

Is there a way of changing the co-ordinate system when using this option? Is there another method that can be used to export the annotations into a tile in British national grid up to level 22?

Alternatively, is there another way to use annotations in ArcGIS online?